# How to display posts in hyperlink with nested slugs?

Tags: theme-development, url-rewriting, rewrite-rules, buddypress

**Important question**

How do i create nesting slugs like  this -- 
127.0.0.1/wordpress/displaypage/family1/members/ 
127.0.0.1/wordpress/displaypage/family2/members/

Here - the slug **displaypage** is the page slug,  and **family1** and **family2** are the name of the groups which i have stored in my custom table..
**members** is the tab which displays the number of users in each group 
Please answer this question

Answer (score 2):

This can be achieved by [adding rewrite rules](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule).

First, [add the query vars](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/query_vars) that will store the custom values in our rules:

```
function wpd_family_query_var( $query_vars ) {
    $query_vars[] = 'wpd_family';
    $query_vars[] = 'wpd_members';
    return $query_vars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'wpd_family_query_var' );
```

Next, add the rules to capture both `displaypage/family/` and `displaypage/family/members/` requests:

```
function wpd_add_family_rewrite_rules() {
    add_rewrite_rule(
        'displaypage/([^/]+)/?$',
        'index.php?pagename=displaypage&wpd_family=$matches[1]',
        'top'
    );
    add_rewrite_rule(
        'displaypage/([^/]+)/members/?$',
        'index.php?pagename=displaypage&wpd_family=$matches[1]&wpd_members=true',
        'top'
    );
}
add_action( 'init', 'wpd_add_family_rewrite_rules' );
```

Don't forget, you must [flush rewrite rules](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/flush_rewrite_rules) after changing them.

You will then be able to access the values of your query vars anywhere [after the `parse_query` action](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference#Actions_Run_During_a_Typical_Request) with [`get_query_var()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_query_var):

```
if( $family = get_query_var( 'wpd_family' ) ){
    echo 'family: ' . $family;
}

if( $members = get_query_var( 'wpd_members' ) ){
    echo 'members: ' . $members;
}
```

Comment: Thank you .. 
I tried this but the last code didn't ouput anything.. Please help me @Milo

Comment: Did you add the first two pieces of code to your theme's functions.php file? Did you flush rewrite rules?

Comment: yes, I have added the customs query vars and also set the rewrite rules.. <br/>
I have set the flush_rewrite_rules() at *init* and  **after_switch_theme** hooks 
and lastly I have added the last part { 
if( $family = get_query_var( 'wpd_family' ) ){
    echo 'family: ' . $family;
}

}  <br/> 
 in index.php of theme template.. but it didn't output anything..  @Milo

Comment: Are the URLs correct, or does it redirect somewhere else? Do you see your page content, and just the query vars aren't working?

Comment: yes, my url is working properly.. all the pages are being displayed...
but just tell me where should i put the last part of code? i guess get_query_var( 'wpd_family' ) should be put in href part..
but just for testing i coded it into index.php page (to test if it outputs anything)..

Comment: You can get the value of your query vars at any point [after the `parse_query` action](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference) runs. Is index.php the template file that loads for those requests?

Comment: No..  page-displaypage.php is the template file ..   how do i know if my query vars has been added.. ? (In Which db table ) ..  Secondly ,  how can I  run my get_query_var function just after the parse_query action ? @Milo

Comment: The that page template is where you can add the code to output those values. Nothing is stored in the database. All the query vars do is hold the value of whatever was extracted from the URL for the lifetime of that single request. What do you want to do with the contents of those query vars?

Comment: Finally..  I understood the concept and it worked.. Thanks to you.. 
and add_rewrite_rule reference page helped me a lot..

Comment: One more thing do I have to hardcode the link; For example:- 
like this - - 
<a href="../wordpress/displaypage/family2/members/ " > Members </a>
Or there is any other method which i should use?